I am a machine that hungers, what am I?
I need help in answering this riddle:

I am a machine that hungers
I am fed constantly by booming shots, blood, and luck
My chewing is metallic and vile
And still I bring more comfort than the dance of hell below
What am I?

This riddle originated from the game "Buckshot Roulette"

@bobble I added the attribution

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
